# Не удается разрешить метод

Tags: java, android-studio

```
private void uploadPicture() {
    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.setTitle("загрузка");
    pd.show();
    final String randomKey = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    StorageReference riversRef = storageProfilePicsRef.child("images/" + randomKey);

    riversRef.putFile(imageUri);
    riversRef.putFile(file)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "image", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    
    addOnFailurelListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed to Uploa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    
    addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progressPercent = (100.00 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
            pd.setMessage("Percentage" + (int) progressPercent + "%");
        }
    });
```

Не удается разрешить методы, `addOnFailurelListener` и `addProgressListener`. Как это исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что значит не удается разрешить методы?

Comment: Cannot resolve method

Comment: А что за закрывающая круглая скобка у вас после реализации методов, но перед точкой с запятой? `addOnFailurelListener(new OnFailureListener() { @Override public void onFailure() {  }  } ) ;`

Comment: Это скобка часть (new OnFailureListener(). Если ее убрать ошибок стало больше.

Comment: `addOnFailurelListener` and `addOnProgressListener` чьи методы? часом не его `StorageReference`?

Answer (score 1):

И так...
Судя по документации метод `putFile` класса `StorageReference` возвращает `UploadTask`
этот класс наследуется от класса `StorageTask` у которого как раз хранятся методы `addOnSuccessListener`, `addOnFailurelListener`, `addOnProgressListener`

Поэтому чтобы получить корректный результат делаем так:

```
UploadTask task = riversRef.putFile(file);
task.addOnSuccessListener(..);
task.addOnFailurelListener(..);
task.addOnProgressListener(..);
```